# how to use cms for updating details on android?

Tags: android, content-management-system

I am new to Android. I am trying to develop an android app where a student can check his details (grades, attendance, courses etc.). My first approach was to create a project with intents and layouts where I could create the xmls but just for static values. Because these values would be getting updated regularly, how do I create a Cms kind of an environment where an admin can update the details and all the student needs to do is just view the details on his android app. I tried searching for a similar question on the website and the internet but nothing helped. I am finished with the xml layouts for all the pages, but I am stuck with the cms concept. I know it's a broad and open ended question but all I am looking for is your opinion on how to approach it in android (CMS/any other alternative). Thanks. Please help.

Comment: First, you need a place to store the data you need and can be accessed by Android device: web server is one of the choices. Second, given the complexity of the data, you can use XML file or database server (or any other choices, these are just examples). If you use XML, you can pull and parse the XML in Android; if you use database, you need an interface to retrieve the data from the DB, then you can process it in Android. Most probably, you also need to use SQLite in Android to store those values and use it in your app.

Answer (score 0):

> You need php files for same where u can create Admin Panel for the
>   same. fire query to php services and refresh Activities in Android
>   thats all u need to do.